# How to populate a dictionary from two related NumPy arrays - alternative to appending

Tags: python, numpy, dictionary

I am trying to learn how to use NP arrays instead of lists. However, I am struggling to identify the proper way to add values to a numpy array when all of the values that belong to the NP array isn't known when creating it intially.

Below is a simplified example of how my previous code looked like, where I am appending values to a list based on what category (country in this example) the values belong to. So the 3rd value in the values list belongs to the 3rd country in the country list (230 belongs to France).

```
country = ['Germany','USA','France','Germany','USA','USA']
values = [250,220,230,180,180,220]

cv = {'Germany':[],'USA':[],'France':[]}

for i in range(len(country)):
    cv[country[i]].append(values[i])
```

This is a simplified example and in reality I need to append values that are much longer, and thus I would like to know what is the most efficient way to rewrite the code in order to end up with a numpy array instead of lists.

Comment: Numpy arrays aren't really meant for that type of operation, as they preallocate memory block on initialisation. The most effecient way is usually just to use lists and then convert to a numpy array at the end.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The fastest way with large arrays will be to use [boolean masking](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/user/basics.indexing.html#boolean-or-mask-index-arrays).

First, wrapping initial lists to NumPy arrays:

```
countries = ['Germany','USA','France','Germany','USA','USA']
values = [250,220,230,180,180,220]
countries = np.array(countries)
values = np.array(values)
```

And now for each unique country filling values of the resulting dict `cv` at once without appending:

```
cv = {country: values[countries == country]
      for country in set(countries)}
print(cv)
```

will give:

```
{'France': array([230]),
 'USA': array([220, 180, 220]),
 'Germany': array([250, 180])}
```

---

**Timings:**

I increased the sizes of the arrays for a more representative example:

```
n = 500
countries = np.array(['Germany','USA','France','Germany','USA','USA'] * n)
values = np.array([250,220,230,180,180,220] * n)

# My version
%%timeit
cv = {country: values[countries == country]
      for country in set(countries)}
# 987 µs ± 5.46 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)

# MathiasRa's version
%%timeit
cv = {'Germany':[],'USA':[],'France':[]}
for i in range(len(countries)):
    cv[countries[i]].append(values[i])
# 1.67 ms ± 9.94 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)

# jpp's version
%%timeit
d = defaultdict(list)
for c, v in zip(countries, values):
    d[c].append(v)
res = {k: np.array(v) for k, v in d.items()}
# 1.5 ms ± 2.37 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)

# Johann Bzh's version
%%timeit
d={}
for c, v in zip(countries, values):
    tmp_vec = np.array([v])
    try:
        d[c] = np.hstack((d[c],tmp_vec))
    except KeyError: #first occurence of this country
        d[c] = tmp_vec  
# 13.3 ms ± 125 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

Answer (score 4):

`np.append` is evil. This isn't an overstatement. NumPy arrays are best used when you can allocate memory in advance. This is where the performance benefits from vectorised operations come into play.

With your data, a better idea is to use `list.append` in a loop using `defaultdict`. Then convert to NumPy via a dictionary comprehension.

```
from collections import defaultdict

country = ['Germany','USA','France','Germany','USA','USA']
values = [250,220,230,180,180,220]

d = defaultdict(list)

for c, v in zip(country, values):
    d[c].append(v)

res = {k: np.array(v) for k, v in d.items()}

print(res)

{'France': array([230]),
 'Germany': array([250, 180]),
 'USA': array([220, 180, 220])}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use [`numpy.hstack()`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.hstack.html).

```
import numpy as np

country = ['Germany','USA','France','Germany','USA','USA']
values = [250,220,230,180,180,220]

d={}

for c, v in zip(country, values):
    tmp_vec = np.array([v])
    try:
        d[c] = np.hstack((d[c],tmp_vec))
    except KeyError: #first occurence of this country
        d[c] = tmp_vec
```

the `try:` `except: KeyError` statement allows to handle the first time a country key is handled. In this case a one valued vector is atteched, in all other cases `hstack()` is used.

Be aware that `hstack()` **returns a copy** and may not be efficient on a large amount of data.